# Find Max(Id) of DbSet<T> where T is unknown

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, generics

How do I find the biggest `Id` of a `DbSet.Set<T>()`?

**Note**: not *`DbSet<TEntity>`*.

I don't know the type at runtime.

**Context**: I have 20 tables/entities, which I'm using a ***generic*** method to do processing.

The process involves looking up the biggest Id of that table/entity and comparing it with the record at hand.

If the record's `id` is bigger than the database's, than it would be inserted into the database.

So far I've tried using reflection:

```
DbSet<T> table = DbContext.Set<T>();
var lastRecord = table.LastOrDefault();  // throws not supported error
var idProperty = lastRecord.GetType().GetProperties()
                                     .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name.Equals("Id");  
int maxId = (int)idProperty.GetValue(lastRecord);
```

I've also tried using an interface cast:

```
interface ICommonEntity
{                              // this interface allows the generic method
    string StringId { get;}    // to know how to handle entity Id's of 
    int? IntId { get; }        // different types (string vs int).
}
```

---

```
var whatever =  table.OrderByDescending(e => (e as ICommonEntity).IntId).FirstOrDefault();
int maxId = (whatever as ICommonEntity).IntId ?? 0;
```

But the above yields the following ***error***:

> The 'TypeAs' expression with an input of type xx is not supported. and a check of type yy. Only entity types and complex types are supported in LINQ to Entities queries

**Additional data:** All my entities have the column/property `Id` of type `int`.
Web searches that I've done mainly point to solutions that the type is known e.g. `TEntity`, db.Users.xxx() etc..

---

### Update

In response to [Ian's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224370/ian-mercer) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49843715/8667400), I can't use `Id` directly. **Why**?
One of my entity has a field named `Id`, but is of type `string`.

```
class EntityStringId : ICommonEntity
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string StringId => Id;
    public int? IntId => null;
}

class EntityIntId : ICommonEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string StringId => null;
    public int? IntId => Id;
}
```

And if I try to use `IntId` for ordering,

```
private void SomeMethod<T>(string file)
    //where T : class           // original
    //where T : ICommonEntity   // cannot. DbContext.Set<T>(); requires class
    where T : class, ICommonEntity  // throws exception
    {
        var table_T = DbContext.Set<T>();
        var maxId = table_T.Max(e => e.IntId); // throws exception ↓
    }
```

> The specified type member 'IntId' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. 
>   Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

For a better picture, my method's logic:

```
private void ProcessCsvToDb<T>(
        DbSet<T> table,
        T csvRecord) where T : class
{
    var iRecord = csvRecord as ICommonEntity;
    T dbRecord = null;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(iRecord.StringId))
    {
        dbRecord = table.Find(iRecord.StringId);
    }
    else if (iRecord.IntId != null)
    {
        dbRecord = table.Find(iRecord.IntId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do all your entities inherit from `ICommonEntity` as you imply in the latter example? Could you just use a generic constraint on your method?

Comment: Yes, they all implement ICommonEntity. I do use generic constraints as required by DbContext.Set<T>();

Comment: If your method uses a generic constraint `where T:ICommonEntity` why do you need to cast it using `as`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to do this without a base class/interface, you will need to manually compose the expression:

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<int> OrderById(Type entityType)
{
    var dbSet = context.Set(entityType);

    var item = Expression.Parameter(entityType, "item");
    var property = Expression.Property(item, "Id");
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, int>>(property, item);
    // the above generates:
    // item => item.Id

    return dbSet.OrderByDescending(lambda);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build expression to sort by Id, but [DynamicQueryable class](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework.Extended/blob/master/Source/EntityFramework.Extended/Dynamic/DynamicQueryable.cs) does it for you:

```
DbSet<T> table = assignFromSomeWhere();
var maxId = table.OrderBy("Id desc").FirstOrDefault();
```

`DynamicQueryable` also gives you different extension methods (dynamic Where, Select). Obviously it is bigger satisfaction to build expressions on your own, but sometimes it is very complicated and this library helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an interface, as discussed in comments, is there any reason you can't do this to avoid the cast:

```
public static int? GetMaxId<T>(DBSet<T> dbSet)
  where T : ICommonEntity
{
  return dbSet.OrderByDescending(e => e.Id).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: I got this error when trying this out: "The specified type member 'IntId' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported."

Comment: @TanSam Why does the interface use `IntId` but the actual entities use `Id`?

Comment: The reason is I created this interface to deal with entities that have string ids and int ids. So its a mix. Its complicated ;)

Comment: I will try this out when I have time. Currently this method is causing some error. Because it needs to be T : class as required by DbSet<T>.